# I am not able to get a 3d track

Tags: tracking

[image: FOOTAGE SINGLE FRAME]

I am trying to 3d track a footage (FOOTAGE DETAILS : 360 rotation drone footage ) . I am not able to get a 3d track , even if i place 8 points manually the camera solve is too high and the camera glides too much , what should i do ??

Comment: Add more than a bare minimum of tracking markers maybe?..

Comment: How long is the footage? Do you have a link to the video so we can see what the footage looks like?

Comment: Maybe you need to scale up the zone and also help manually?